# How to properly use .Net Core Generic Host without IHostedService?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

We have legacy application that we plan to transition to the ASP.NET Core API (v2.2) some time in future.
In order to make it easier, we decided to start using Generic Host with all the available features for all future enhancements (appsettings/logging/DI etc.). 
The idea is that once we switch to the API, we will copy the host configuration and majority of the code will keep working. We will expose the host.Services.GetService() to the legacy codebase which will use it as a simple ServiceLocator.

Question is: is there any downside of using such approach? Also, do we need to use Start/Stop/Run on the generic host? Based on what I've read, this is only needed for running the IHostedService which we don't plan to use. I tested if it works without calling Start/Stop and everything seems to be fine but all the examples I found do call Start/Stop, even without IHostedService.

```
        private IHost _host;
        private PricingHost()
        {
            _host = new HostBuilder()
                .UseEnvironment("BETA")
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, configApp) =>
                {
                    configApp.SetBasePath(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
                    configApp.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true);
                    configApp.AddJsonFile(
                        $"appsettings.{hostContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json",
                        optional: true);
                })
                .ConfigureLogging((hostContext, configLogging) =>
                {
                    configLogging.AddConfiguration(hostContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
                    configLogging.AddDebug();
                    configLogging.AddConsole();
                    configLogging.AddCustomLogger();
                })
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, configServices) =>
                {
                    var startup = new Startup(hostContext.Configuration);
                    startup.ConfigureServices(configServices);
                })
                .Build();
        }

        public T GetService<T>()
        {
            return _host.Services.GetService<T>();
        }

        public T GetRequiredService<T>()
        {
            return _host.Services.GetRequiredService<T>();
        }
```

**UPDATE:** let me try to clarify. We have legacy, 10years old windows service. We plan to transition it to asp.net .net core api some time in the future BUT there is still an ongoing work on the windows service right now. In order to simplify future transition we want to use generic host for DI, config access, logging etc. We simply want to use it as a service locator (so no need for IHostedService) but have an ability some time in future to be able to just copy all the configuration/setup and paste it into the new API

After doing small POC I know that this is totally possible but what I'm trying to figure out is if there are any pitfalls I should be aware of and how to properly use GenericHost without IHostedService (do I need to call Run/Start/Stop at some point or it is unnecessary)?

**UPDATE:** Adding dot net fiddle example of what I'm doing [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rqThcV)

Comment: Sorry but I think I did not get your problem. You want to migrate you API from 2.2 to 3.1 with Generic Host, right? [Have you read this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio). You are not bound to use ```IHostedService``` BUT I think in every other case then an API it make totally sense to use it :)

Comment: @Martin sorry for not being clear. The question is actually about what is the proper way of using GenericHost without IHostedService (do I need to call Run/Start/Stop/etc. or do anything else) and if there are any problems I should be aware of while using GenericHost as a ServiceLocator by exposing host.Services.GetService<T>() to the legacy codebase. I updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok from my comment and your answer I will try to find an answer :)

I think if you really need to use the service locator pattern instead of a dependency injection you can also register in the dependency injection the `IServiceProvider` itself

### First step: Register the service provider (`IServiceProvider`)

```
private static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder()
{
    // One host for all services
    return new HostBuilder()
        .UseEnvironment("BETA")
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, configApp) =>
        {
            // your configuration
            configApp.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true);
        })
        .ConfigureLogging((hostContext, configLogging) =>
        {
            configLogging.AddConsole();
        })
        .ConfigureServices((hostContext, configServices) =>
        {
            // your services
            configServices.AddHostedService<PricingHost>();

            // register the service provider as singleton
            configServices.AddSingleton<IServiceProvider>(sp => sp);
        });
}
```

### Second Step: Use `IHostedService`

Like you said you do not want to use `IHostedService` but as I understand you want to instanciate multiple `IHost` classes which is at the end very unhandy. So I think the best solution is to implement it with `IHostedServices` use the code from your old projects in the `StartAsync(...)`-methods and let them run "forever" eighter with a `while` loop or a `Task.Delay(forever)` and use the `IServiceProvider` as service locator.

```
// Each service as IHostedService
public class PricingHost : IHostedService 
{
    // Usage as: Service Locator
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public PricingHost(IServiceProvider sp)
    {
        _serviceProvider = sp;  
    }

    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken token)
    {
        Task.Run(() => RunningTask(token));

        await Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite, token);
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken token)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private Task RunningTask(CancellationToken token)
    {
        // do your things ...
        var logger = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<PricingHost>>();
        logger.LogInformation("Working...");

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Maybe it is more clear if you look to my short
[Example on dotnet fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Dnx8R1)

Leave me a comment if there is anything unclear. Maybe I did not get it right why you want to have multiple hosts in your application.

Comment: Thanks @Martin for taking time to look into this, really appreciate it! I feel like we almost there :) 
Here is what I'm doing right now https://dotnetfiddle.net/rqThcV
I don't need multiple IHost instances so that's why I'm using it as singleton (don't have DI in legacy app). I understand that best way would be to start IHostedService that will start ExistingWebService but this is just too big of a change and I will never get approval to do this. Existing code will not (can not) be changed in any way so this is the reason why I'm using IHost in such a manner

Comment: using the example from my dot net fiddle, once we decide to switch to asp.net core api, I will copy configuration from Startup + copy newly built Services etc. and place it into api. The only thing I will have to do is to call these newly created services (from controllers for example) and majority of newly created functionality will just start working. This is the general idea of what I'm trying to accomplish

Comment: Sorry for staying on the idea to use IHostedService but is this something with do-able in your case: [dotnet fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/k3xVmc)? - There you have 1 host, multiple services, legacy and DI :)

Comment: Is there any specific reason why we should use it in such a way? I understand that this is how it was supposed to be used, but what are the downsides of using it our way? The thing is that the legacy app is deployed as both windows service and soap web service and switching it to hosted services will most likely require changes to the ci/cd as well as ot will require a lot of regression testing and potentially will cost a lot of money while I dont understand how we will benefit from it

Comment: There are downside. I just tried to make an example which also can help you to have it easier to move from IHost (or legacy webservice) to IHostedService with less code changes as possible. I understand your problem very well had the same here too. We tried it step-by-step like you did and afterwards a larger step to IHostedServices was taken at all. It all depends how large your steps can be in step-by-step scenario :)

Comment: ... sorry: there are *no* downsides. cannot edit my comment anymore :(